# How to check if the current page is a plugin admin panel in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Please I want to know how to check if I'm currently in admin page of a plugin.
I've created a plugin with a menu item which displays a page containing some stats of this plugin use, for that, I'm using custom JQuery plugins, some CSS, which I will never use outside of this page.

So I wonder to know how can I check this, to enqueue or not plugin's styles and JSs .

Here is my enqueue style code

```
function bridge_style_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_style( "bridge_display_style", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/symfony-bridge/chosen.css');
   wp_register_style( "bridge_display_style_tb", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/symfony-bridge/bootstrap.min.css');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bridge_display_style' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bridge_display_style_tb' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'bridge_style_enqueuer' );
```

I do the same with Js

```
function bridge_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "bridge_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/symfony-bridge/bridge.js', array('jquery'),FASLE, TRUE);
   wp_register_script( "bridge_chosen_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/symfony-bridge/chosen.js', array('jquery'),FASLE, TRUE);
   wp_register_script( "bridge_chosen_script_tb", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/symfony-bridge/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),FASLE, TRUE);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bridge_script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bridge_chosen_script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bridge_chosen_script_tb' );
}
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'bridge_script_enqueuer' );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [WP Screen](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/) API:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( in_array( $screen->id, array( 'some_admin_page', 'another_admin_page' ) ) )
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bridge_script' );
}
```

Note that you can simply register the scripts on the `init` or `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook (as you did), and enqueue them "in-page", i.e. in the callback function for `add_menu_page()`.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do it is using [`add_*_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [`admin_print_scripts-$your_plugin_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_page_so_20162413' );

function add_page_so_20162413()
{
    $my_page = add_menu_page( /* etc */ );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$my_page", 'enqueue_so_20162413' );
}

function enqueue_so_20162413()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( /* etc */ );
    wp_enqueue_style( /* etc */ );
}
```

<sub>*[Diggy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162413/how-to-check-if-the-current-page-is-a-plugin-admin-panel-in-wordpress/20164458#20164458) is the best one when we're having problems enqueuing with this method.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add js by the hook `admin_enqueue_scripts` -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts.
And, by the way, actually for adding scripts and css's you should to use hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, But it still not resolve my problem, which is how to know if I'm currently in my plugin admin page.